# Accessing bearer token every few mins in Azure

Tags: azure, rest, oauth-2.0, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline which has an associated trigger which executes it in a fixed cycle (e.g. every 15 mins scheduled trigger). It calls some REST APIs associated with Azure resources. So every time it needs to get a bearer token. Now it's not a good idea to get bearer token every 15 mins because bearer tokens are valid up to an hour (is it a problem if we do get fresh bearer token every 15 mins?). So is there any way to persist and use the same token up to an hour? I could be storing it in a key vault but again I need to issue a REST call to access it from key vault -- so what's the benefit then. What's the standard Azure recommended way to get bearer token when we are going to need it pretty much now and then (say every 10-15 mins)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a problem worth solving to me. I assume you're using the client credential flow to acquire the token, so no user interaction is needed. It should be fine to get a new token every 15 minutes.

Caching this token somewhere will make your solution more complicated with virtually no benefit. Azure AD does not care whether you call it once an hour or 4 times an hour.

Comment: Yes in fact my question is about caching token itself. Like what is the standard caching solution for caching token? I am not bothered about user interaction , because I am already using app id. So the question is totally about caching token. The reason I am worried about getting fresh token every 15 mins is that I was concerned about hitting any internal API limits. But I guess the limit is too high to be bothered about in this case right?

Comment: Obviously, since you're dealing with bearer tokens, you want to make sure the token cannot be stolen. You could cache it in the filesystem or in memory. But I still think you shouldn't bother with it unless you actually run into some limit.